# How to change the new MS Access latest version design?

Tags: ms-access

I updated my MS Access database and now the Access object panel has a really large icons for tables, reports, forms, macros etc. It also has a lot of unnecessary information like Date Created and Date Modified under all of the database objects.

Is there a way to change the look of the Access Objects panel and make it look like what is was before?

Comment: Right click on the panel header "All Access Objects".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose large icons (icons)

You can choose list (a list, smaller, usually the default)

You can choose details (large icons, with date + descriptions)

Simply right click on all access objects, then view by.

You should see this:

[image]